# Overriding private property in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Can't explain why this prints "\n1". Private property can't be inherited. That's why constructor should set value of new defined public proverty, but "print $b->number" prints nothing whereas "$b->printNumber()" prints "1".

```
class A 
{
    private $number;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function printNumber()
    {
        print $this->number;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public $number;
}

$b = new B(1);
print $b->number;
print "\n";
$b->printNumber();
```

Answer (score 3):

The private is defined in "A". As printNumber() is also defined in "A" it will access $this->number in the scope of class "A". So the result is expected.

```
class B extends A
{
    public $number;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }
}
```

Of course you would never override a private with a public ;)